# Django Authentication not affecting internal apps

Tags: python, django

First, let me say I'm new to Django and I'm still learning the ropes.
I recently installed the django-registration package. Everything works fine except for one small glitch with logins/authentication. /accounts/login works fine and user.authenticated is fine. Within my app directory/folder is where the problem is. I can't seem to call user.authenticated, it always return False. But outside this app directory everything is fine.
I can even do /users/()

What am I missing? Should I add anything to settings.py?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Thanks people for your comments. Here is it, I have a base.html file when I check localhost/accounts/login - I can see that the user.authenticated function works fine, it doesn't return false, this is after a successful login. If I check the root of the main app on localhost nothing user.authenticated always return false.

Comment: This question is very broad. Consider describing the steps you are trying to do in more detail.

Comment: "But outside this app directory everything is fine." Please, help us understand this sentence

Comment: Thanks people for your comments. Here is it, I have a base.html file when I check localhost/accounts/login - I can see that the user.authenticated function works fine, it doesn't return false, this is after a successful login. If I check the root of the main app on localhost nothing user.authenticated always return false. Hope this helps.